# How do I append an initially empty string array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a variable number of items to a string array.

My code is in a worksheet change function:

```
            Dim StartNums(0 To 2) As String

            doneColor = RGB(175, 175, 175)

            cmt = FRg.Comment.Text


            rowLen = InStr(1, cmt, vbLf)
            If rowLen = 0 Then
                rowLen = Len(cmt)
            End If
            numChunks = rowLen / 32
            numRows = Len(cmt) / rowLen
'            For i = 1 To 12 'FRg.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Count
'                With FRg.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1)
'                    If .Font.Strikethrough = True Then
'                        .Font.Color = vbGreen
'                    End If
'                End With
'            Next i
            MsgBox ("About to fill StartNums, nothing should be in it yet")
            For j = 0 To numChunks - 1
                MsgBox ("going to add stuff for chunk " & j)
                If Not UBound(StartNums) = 2 Then
'                    MsgBox ("resizing an empty array")
'                    ReDim Preserve StartNums(3) As Variant
'                Else
                    'MsgBox ("resizing a non-empty array")
                    ReDim Preserve StartNums(UBound(StartNums) + 3) As String
                End If

                StartNums(UBound(StartNums) - 2) = (j * 32) + 5 + (0 * 9)
                StartNums(UBound(StartNums) - 1) = (j * 32) + 5 + (1 * 9)
                StartNums(UBound(StartNums) - 0) = (j * 32) + 5 + (2 * 9)
            Next j
```

Now whenever I go into the worksheet, the ReDim line has a Compile Error `Array already dimensioned`.  I'm aware it's already dimensioned, which is why I'm ReDim-ing it.

How do I add 3 more spaces in an array?

Comment: if you know there will be 3 more spaces, why not just declare the correct size? you can have empty values in an array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When  you initially `Dim` it, you can't give it the size if you plan on changing the size later:

so instead of

```
Dim StartNums(0 To 2) As String
```

You would use

```
Dim StartNums() As String
```

and then on the next line

```
ReDim StartNums(0 To 2)
```

note, you can also use this, as it's assumed to be 0 based by default.

```
ReDim StartNums(2)
```

That will accomplish the same thing, but then you can later use `Redim Preserve` to change the size of it.